# How can I get the correct instance of IMemoryCache in a Timer Callback or in a method fired my a Task?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, memorycache

I'm trying to use an `IMemoryCache` instance injected in a services that has a Timer which fires a method every x minutes.The same `IMemoryCache` interface is injected in a controller constructor which, for each request, should add an object to a list and save it to cache. My problem is that when I'm trying to get the object list from cache, called in the service that fires every x minutes, I don't get the correct instance (my list is null). I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and as a type of project I have a Web API.

PS. Instead of a Timer I tried with a `Task` but I have the same behavior. I also tried to make  DI cache resolver in my fired method. I guess is a thread problem. Here is my code:
In startup:

```cs
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddScoped<SyncService>();
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

//I do this to fire my timer from the constructor
var syncService = sp.GetService<SyncService>();
```

My controller:

```cs
public class TestController : BaseApiController
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public TestController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<bool> AckRequest([FromBody] Ack ack)
    {

        if (ack != null)
        {
            List<Ack> ackList;

            //I always get the correct value for each request
            _cache.TryGetValue("ack", out ackList);       
            if (ackList != null)
            {
                ackList.Add(ack);
                _cache.Set("ack", ackList);
            }
            else
            {
                var newList = new List<Ack>();
                newList.Add(ack);
                _cache.Set("ack", newList);
            }
            return Ok(true);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

My SyncService:

```cs
public class SyncService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    public SyncService(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;

        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Interval = 1 * 60 * 1000;
        myTimer.Elapsed += SyncWithDatabase;
        myTimer.Start();

         //Task task = new Task(() =>    //tried with a Task too
         //{
         //    while (true)
         //    {
         //        SyncWithDatabase();
         //        Thread.Sleep(1 * 60 * 1000);
         //    }
         //});
         //task.Start();
    }
    public void SyncWithDatabase(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Ack> ackList;
        _cache.TryGetValue("ack", out ackList);  //the list is always null
    }
}
```

Comment: In what context does your service run? Is it in the same web application, or an entirely separate Windows Service? Also, are you sure a cache is what you need here? This code has concurrency issues.

Comment: Both the Controller and the Service are in the same WebApi.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, we can find that you create a new service provider by calling  BuildServicesProvider method, which cause the cache instance that you used to set the value is not the same as the one that you used to retrieve the value in `SyncService`.

To achieve same requirement, you can try to implement it as a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks).

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public TimedHostedService(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {

        List<Ack> ackList;
        _cache.TryGetValue("ack", out ackList);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Register `TimedHostedService` in `ConfigureServices` method of Startup class.

```
services.AddMemoryCache();

services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the solution. Saved my day!

Comment: Hi @user3542654, if it did help achieve the requirement, you can accept it as answer.